# Salesforce - insert record to PricebookEntry table for Standard pricebook

Tags: insert, salesforce

I have been trying to insert new records to PricebookEntry table for standard pricebook. I need to do this since I need to insert record for custom pricebook. However, it keep getting error.

Here is my code:

```
Pricebook2 standardpricebook = [select id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
System.debug(standardpricebook.id);
PricebookEntry standardprice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = standardpricebook.id, Product2Id = Product2Id[i], Name__c=Name[i], UnitPrice = 0.00, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice=false);
insert standardprice;
```

This code failed with this error:

Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, This price definition already exists in this price book: []

After few hour of researching, I found this website, http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/03/salesforce-obscure-field-integrity.html

which indicate I have to set the UseStandardPrice to true. If I do this, it get this error:

Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: []

According to the website above, I can't set the UnitPrice when UseStandardPrice set to true. Is there anyway to insert the record with standard pricebook?

Thank you

Comment: Are you still alive? Please select my answer as best answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You ALWAYS need to use `UseStandardPrice = FALSE` for the FIRST pricebookentry you make. I did it programmatically myself.

If you add manually in Salesforce UI itself, they will default the `UseStandardPrice = FALSE` too.

That is by design because once you set the Standard Price then only you can have the option to UseStandardPrice on subsequent pricebookentries.

Also in future ask this question in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/